# How to auto beautify designer in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

By default, when selecting Designer tab of a database all tables are stacked on each others. Which looks something like this:
[image: phpmyadmin stacked tables in designer]
Is there any way to auto organize them near each other?
I'm using phpmyadmin 5.0.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to automatically sort these.

Once you sort them manually, you can save the layout. You first have to have the [phpMyAdmin configuration storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) database and a controluser set up. From the fold-out menu, click the "Save page" or "Save page as" buttons. You'll probably be prompted for a name, and the coordinates of all of the tables will be saved to the phpmyadmin database in the table specified by `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']` - by default, this is `pma__pdf_pages`.

Answer (score 0):

So the basic problem is that you need an arranged ERD design for your whatever database you are referring. I was facing the problem and so far I found this solution that we can render the ERD diagram from a chrome extension

> Chrome MySQL Admin

.

You can find it here.

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-mysql-admin/ndgnpnpakfcdjmpgmcaknimfgcldechn?hl=en

- You can connect with your phpmyadmin by the default config
- Select You Database
- Click on screen icon top-right of the window
- You will be then rendering your ERD.